# web service returning xml although return format is json

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

Here is the web service

```
public class HelloWorld : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Here is the javascript ajax code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Service/HelloWorld.asmx/Hello",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            timeout: 15000,
            success: function (rtndata) {
                alert('Success : :' + rtndata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
                alert("Excep:: " + exception + "Status:: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Getting error

```
    Excep:: Invalid JSON: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>Status:: OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've ScriptHandlerFactory setting under Handler section in web.config.

```
<httpHandlers>
     <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
     <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false"
          type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,
          System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
          PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

For more information check out below link:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services

**Edit**

I would suggest that you go through below blog post of Dave Ward that discusses  Installation and configuration mistakes:

http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpPost=true, ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Also return an object from your service so that it can be used more predictably by the client.

```
return new Result() { Value = "some string" };
```